# How to redirect by drop down option to different actions in the same php file on submit?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Hi I am new in this area and the question might sounds ambiguous... What I am trying to achieve is, I want to search for a property entry with keywords of suburb and property type. So when I type in a keyword, such as "House", and choose the "property type" option in the drop down menu and click submit, the file will take action to give me the searched results.

Here's the code to give you a better picture

> ## search.php

```
if(!isset($_POST['key']))
{
?>
 <center><h2><font face="verdana">Search For Property </font></h2>
        
<form method="post" id="form_search">
Enter a keyword <input ="text" name="key"><br><br>

 <select id ="searchOpt" form = "form_search" >
  <option selected disabled> Search by...</option>
  <option  value = "type"> Property Type  </option>
  <option  value = "suburb"> Suburb  </option>
  </select>

  <input type="submit" id = "searchOpt" formaction="
      <?php echo ($_POST["searchOpt"]="type")?'search.php?&Action=type':'search.php?&Action=suburb';?>">

</form>

</center>

<?php
}
else
{
 switch($_GET["Action"]) 
{
  case "suburb":
// show "suburb" results
  break;
  case "type":
// show "suburb" results
  break;
}
}
```

As you can see I am trying to pass the option value to the back of "search.php?&Action=" in order to use the switch function below. However, no matter which option I chose, I am always getting the results from the case "type" but not the suburb. Does anyone know how to fix this? Can I use html codes to fix this problem only? If javascript or JQuery are to be resorted, can you go through the codes line by line for me? Much appreciated!

Comment: `<input ="text" name="key">` is this just copy/paste typo? It should be `<input type="text" name="key">`

Comment: `($_POST["searchOpt"]="type")` should be `($_POST["searchOpt"]=="type")` ! You're overwriting $_POST, not comparing.

Comment: @VuralAcar Thanks(: and regarding my question, any thoughts?

Comment: I get a undefined index notice regarding "searchOpt" now@Jeff

Comment: yeah, I see. I think your whole logic is a bit complicated and inconsistent.

Comment: why don't you pass searchOpt as a normal POST-parameter with the form? You can then also do a `switch ($_POST['searchOpt') {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see you don't need that tricky workaround with formaction if you simply send `searchOpt` with the form as Post parameter:

```
if(!isset($_POST['key']))
{
?>
 <center><h2><font face="verdana">Search For Property </font></h2>

<form method="post" id="form_search" action="search.php">
Enter a keyword <input type="text" name="key"><br><br>

<select name="searchOpt" >
  <option selected disabled> Search by...</option>
  <option  value = "type"> Property Type  </option>
  <option  value = "suburb"> Suburb  </option>
</select>

<input type="submit" id="searchOpt">

</form>

</center>

<?php
}
else
{
  switch($_POST["searchOpt"]) 
  {
      case "suburb":
           // show "suburb" results
           break;
     case "type":
          // show "suburb" results
          break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to make your code more understandable and it works :

try code below:

php:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['key']))
  {
    //do someting, after you got the search key.
    switch($_POST["action"]) 
    {
       case "suburb":
       echo "You have selected suburb";
       break;
       case "type":
       echo "You have selected type";
       break;
    }
  }

  function isSelected($value)
  {
    return (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == $value) 
            ? "selected='selected'" 
            : "";
  }
?>
```

html: I have tried to make it as simple as possible

```
<?php if(!isset($_POST['key']): ?>
<center><h2><font face="verdana">Search For Property </font></h2>
<form action="#" name="form_search" method="post" id="form_search">
    Enter a keyword: <input type="text" name="key">
    <br /><br />
    <select id = "searchOpt" name = "action">
       <option> Search by...</option>
      <option value = "type" <?php echo isSelected('type'); ?>>Property Type</option>
      <option value = "suburb" <?php echo isSelected('suburb'); ?>>Suburb</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" id = "searchOpt" name="submit" value="Search">

</form>
</center>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering... but I am trying to stay at the same page but not going to another php file... I am going to use a switch later in this file. The option is used to turn the switch to "type" or "suburb"

Comment: so I am not passing values to another file. i just pass it to the code I am using later in the exact same file

Comment: well, I really don't know what you are trying to achive, I will change the action for you, so you will stay on the same page

Comment: Just try it now please.

Comment: Thats not I am trying to achieve.. but still thanks. I have applied method of Jeff's

Comment: just to be clear: our both solutions are mainly the same, except @Vural Acar added the "selected" state.